# Javascript IE Error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Error can be seen here: http://client.bytewire.co.uk/marblesolar/roof-calculator/

Anyone no how to solve this error in IE:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Fri, 4 Nov 2011 18:01:09 UTC

Message: 'null' is null or not an object
Line: 30
Char: 1383
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/6/11/main.js

The script isn't even being run at this point so not sure where the error resides from.

Comment: No clue whatsoever unless we can see your code. Preferably a minimal testcase.

Comment: It is exteremly difficult to find the issue, the way you have asked.How have you used the script in your code?

Comment: Using Internet Explorer is an error in and of itself.

Comment: Added a link to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `Can't find variable: map` error within Safari too.

It's likely because you are referencing the `map` variable before you've defined it...

```
 var creator = new PolygonCreator(map);
```